# Index in array showing undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

for some reason the index number is showing undefined when trying to splice it from the allcontacts array, do you know why this is happening? Thank you.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

                let allcontacts = [];
                let index = 0;

                $(document).on('click', "#addcontact", function() {

                    let contact = [];
                    index++;

                    const eachemail = $(this).closest('#contactdiv').find('#emailinput').not(this).val();
                    const eachname = $(this).closest('#contactdiv').find('#nameinput').not(this).val();
                    const eachtype = $(this).closest('#contactdiv').find('#contacttype').not(this).val();

                    contact.push(eachemail, eachname, eachtype);
                    allcontacts.push(contact);

                });

                $(document).on('click', "#removecontact", function() {
                    allcontacts.splice(index);
                    $(this).closest('#contactdiv').remove();

                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The first value in an array has an index "0", so if the array is empty the index is "-1".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   let allcontacts = [];
   let index = -1;
});
```

Comment: But i get the index number from the global defined index variable? So shouldn't i be able to access the index in the #removecontact function

Comment: Indeed you get the global index.

What I see is that by default the index is 0 and your array "allcontacts" is empty. Except that in an array the index 0 means that there is one value.

Comment: Try to set global index as -1.